# How to display three digits before the decimal point?

Tags: php, decimal, digits

I would like to know how to display at least three digits before the decimal point?

For example:

```
$nb_badge = "001";
$nb_badge = $nb_badge+6;
echo $nb_badge; // Must display "007".
```

Comment: Using [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)..... `echo sprintf('%03d', $nb_badge);`

Comment: Alternatively, `str_pad`.

Comment: it's in time like these that I miss a `left-pad` library for php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$nb_badge = sprintf("%03d", $nb_badge);
```